# AMPL Syntax Error around ";"

Tags: syntax, ampl

New to AMPL, getting a syntax error in the following model siting ">>>>> ; <<<<<<" as the problem:

```
set Types;
param demand {Types};
set Machines;
param prod_cost {Machines, Types};
param days_reqd {Machines, Types};
param days_avail {Machines};

var x {Machines, Types} >=0;  # amount produced

minimize  total_cost:  sum {m in Machines, t in Types} prod_cost[m,t] * x[m,t] ;

subject to  machine_capacity: sum {m in Machines, t in Types} x[m,t] * days_reqd[m,t] <= days_avail[m] ;

subject to  satisfy_demand: sum {m in Machines, t in Types} x[m,t] >= demand ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `demand` parameter is indexed over set `Types` and therefore requires a subscript, e.g.

```
subject to  satisfy_demand{t in Types}:
  sum {m in Machines} x[m,t] >= demand[t] ;
```